# What are the dates of Subala and Mudgala Upanishads?

Tags: history, upanishads

Scholarly opinion is as follows:

https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmXoypizjW3WknFiJnKLwHCnL72vedxjQkDDP1mXWo6uco/wiki/Mudgala_Upanishad.html

> The author or composition date of Mudgala Upanishad is unknown. Jan Gonda – a professor of Sanskrit and Dutch Indologist, states it is a late Upanishad.[4] The style and structure of Sanskrit words used by the text suggest it to be a medieval text.[7][8] The text, states Klaus Witz, is a post-Vedic but early Vaishnava Upanishad.[9] The Upanishad reflects an integration and a harmony of Vedic doctrines with those of Vaishnava doctrines.[10]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subala_Upanishad

> The Subala Upanishad, together with the relatively older Mudgala Upanishad, are two Upanishads that discuss the Purusha Sukta of Rigveda,[5] both notable for asserting that Narayana (Vishnu) is the Brahman (Highest Reality, Supreme Being).[5][6][7] The Subala Upanishad text differs from Mudgala Upanishad in presenting more verses of the Purusha Sukta,[5][8] being longer, and for declaring Narayana to be the father, the mother, the refuge, the friend and the goal of every living being.[4][6]

---

> The author or composition date of Subala Upanishad is unknown. Hans Hock states that it is a late Upanishadic text.[12]

Is this the consensus as to the dates of these texts?

Comment: I dont remember Sri Shankara quoting either of these two upanishads.

Answer (score 2):

> What are the dates of Subala and Mudgala Upanishads?

**Eternal.**

The Vedas are eternal.

> **[Manu 1.23](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc145422.html)** - From out of (the three deities) Agni, Vāyu and Ravi, he extracted, for the due fulfilment of sacrifices, **the eternal Brahman**, threefold, in the forms of ‘Ṛk,’ ‘Yajuṣ’ and ‘Sāman.’

Comment: So every such Upanishads are Vedas?

Comment: @Rickross All the authentic Upanishads are Vedas. The Upanishads are at the end of the Brahmanas of the Vedas.

Comment: Oh I see . Brahmans are of course much later day texts .. Veda means only the Samhitas .. Don't u know that Veda Vyasa divided the Samhitas of Vedas and got his name? Did he divide the Upanishads or anything else?

Comment: @Rickross That's a good question and I posted that exact question on this site. Bhagavata Purana says he divided the *Samhitas*. I'm not sure how the Brahmanas, Aranyakas, and Upanishads originated, but Shankara, Ramanuja, etc. all say that whole Veda is eternal.

Comment: That's actually an answer not a Q .. Shankara or any other person saying something is NO proof for me

Comment: @Rickross I meant that I posted on this site whether Vyasa divided just the Samhitas or whether he divided the whole Veda. And what I meant by Shankara, etc. is that all Vedic scholars today accept the Samhitas and Upanishads to be eternal.

Comment: Vyasa simply divided the Vedas and so only Samhitas=Vedas .. Scholars can believe anything just like Vivekananda felt Max to be rebirth of Sayana .. Do u consider that as a proof?

Comment: @Rickross It's possible Vyasa divided the Samhitas, but the Upanishads, Aranyakas, and Brahmanas were revealed through other Rishis after Vyasa divided the Samhitas. And yes, the words of guru paramparas and sampradayas of vedic scholars going back to Vyasa, is a type of shabda pramana, insofar as it doesn't contradict scripture.